# Shift all dates in MySQL database by specific delta value

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

Is there a way in MySQL to shift all date/datetime columns in a database by a calculated delta value?

I want to take the max date from a static table and column (table and column always the same) and subtract that from the curdate() value to get the number of days behind *now* that said max is. Then I want to *shift* all date/datetime values in the database by that number, effectively bringing all records in the database to the current time.

I know that I can use the `information_schema.columns` attribute to do pull all columns of date/datetime, but I'm unsure how to build this into a working "and sane" query to do the update.

I was thinking of something like:

```
SELECT concat('UPDATE ', table_name, ' set ', column_name, ' = date_add(', column_name, ', INTERVAL datediff(curdate(), max(given_table.given_column)) day);')
from information_schema.columns
where data_type in ('date', 'datetime') and table_schema = 'mydatabase';`
```

But there are multiple problems with this, obviously, so I know I can't use this.

Is there a way to calculate a delta between X database column and now, and then shift all date/datetime columns in the database by that value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's any magic bullet here, maybe just cleaning up your query a bit.  I tried the following and it seemed to work fine for my databases:

```
 select @diff_in_days := datediff(curdate(), max(given_column))
   from given_table
;

 select concat(
            'update ', table_name,
              ' set ', column_name, ' = date_add(',
                            column_name,
                            ', interval ', @diff_in_days, ' day',
                       ');'
        )
   from information_schema.columns
  where data_type in ('date', 'datetime') and table_schema = 'mydatabase'
;
```

And to execute it, one way is to put the above in generate.sql, then do:

```
mysql < generate.sql > update.sql
mysql < update.sql
```

Of course with the proper parameters for your server, database, user, etc.

Comment: Ahh, the magic bullet would probably be: use a variable instead of shoving it all into one line so you can see what's going on. Thanks!

Comment: Currently, this is just returning rows of NULL (makes sense, given no return from update) but it's not writing any updates. I wonder if I need to explicitly state that this select needs to be executed. (Duh, RTFM… EXECUTE)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought you were using this to create like a script file to run.  Editing.

Comment: Actually, A file for script might actually be just as good if not better.

Comment: Yeah, that's my thinking - see the edit above and you're welcome to fix it if my mysql memory fails me :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40329/discussion-between-johnmetta-and-milimetric)